# How to check double condition smarty

Tags: php, if-statement, smarty

I want to check if the variable $nvTb is 1 or 2.

I'm doing this but not working

```
{if (($nvTb eq 1) or ($nvTb eq 2)) }
```

to achieve something like this

```
<a role="tab" {if (($nvTb eq 1) or ($nvTb eq 2)) } id="fichaScroll" {else} data-toggle="tab" {/if}>
```

When I run the code with only one if check like

```
{if $nvTb eq 1}
```

then works

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with that syntax but it is definitely not vanilla PHP. I am also unclear how this relates to TPL. If you're using templating then make sure you mention which templating engine you're using.

Comment: I don't know if it's Vanilla PHP. It's related to TPL because I'm using templates in the whole code, maybe not related to this thread specifically

Comment: `<a role="tab" {if ($nvTb eq 1 or $nvTb eq 2) } id="fichaScroll" {else} data-toggle="tab" {/if}> `

Comment: I just realised that you added TPL as in the extension TPL and not the .NET API . You should have tagged this with "smarty" instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that TPL was meant to be for `smarty` templates judging by the syntax which you can get the full documentation from here: http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/

`eq` is an alias of `==` which you can see here: http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.if.tpl

In terms of your problem, try the following:

```
<a role="tab" {if $nvTb === 1 || $nvTb === 2} id="fichaScroll" {else} data-toggle="tab" {/if}>
```

`eq` is an alias of `==` so that means that it will treat `1` as true, meaning that anything that any truth-ee value will also pass the check. I'm guessing that might be your problem.

If that isn't the problem try the following:

```
{php}
echo '<a role="tab" ((if $nvTb === 1 || $nvTb === 2) ? id="fichaScroll" 
                                                     : data-toggle="tab")>';
{/php}
```

Not the prettiest solution by any means but I believe it should work.

Comment: I think this is the most accurate approach but still not working. It's strange because when I execute the if statements alone, that is {if $nvTb eq 1} or {if $nvTb eq 2} separately, they both work. The first one scrolls the screen from the first subdivision to top and the second one from second subdivision to top. But when altogether, they are not working.

Answer (score 1):

in php you can do something like this

```
<?php if(($nvTb == 1) ||  if($nvTb == 2)) {


}?>
```

Answer (score 1):

That looks like Smarty. Try it like this:

```
{if $nvTb == 1 || $nvTb == 2}
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this :

```
<?php 
switch($nvTb) {
    case 1:
        //your code here
    case 2:
        //your code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using smarty try this

```
{if ($nvTb eq 1) || ($nvTb eq 2)}
    do something
{/if}
```

In your case

```
<a role="tab" {if ($nvTb eq 1) || ($nvTb eq 2)} id="fichaScroll" {else} data-toggle="tab" {/if}>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no "eq" in php just use == ->

```
if ($nvTb == 1 || $nvTb == 2)
```

Note: There is also a typesafe compare in php ===
For more Infos look here http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison

Comment: It's a smarty template where `eq` is an alias of `==`

Comment: sorry for the confusion, but smarty was not tagged in the question at the time of this answer. I'm aware that there is always a possibility that some Syntax come from outside the vanilla-php world. But as long as nothing is mentioned in the question, i have to suppose, it is copied code which does not run in vanilla php

Answer (score 0):

In the end, the error was located in the id section. When having several sections and using the same id can result in an error. To solve this I used classes instead like this:

```
<a role="tab" {if ($nvTb eq 1) || ($nvTb eq 2)} class="fichaScroll" {else} data-toggle="tab" {/if}>
```

And changed the javascript from # to .

Once done that the double if statement works fine.